# Make a list of tensor of uniform shape

Tags: python, tensorflow

I've a list of tensors, in which each tensor is of different shape. I want to pad zero to tensors to make the overall list of tensors uniform.

Example:

```
input: [[1],[2,2],[3,3,3],[4,4,4,4],[5,5,5,5,5]]
output: [[1,0,0,0,0],[2,2,0,0,0],[3,3,3,0,0],[4,4,4,4,0],[5,5,5,5,5]]
```

I tried using a map function but it's giving me error. Here, is my code

```
value = tf.constant([1,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4,4,5,5,5,5,5])
y, idx, count = tf.unique_with_counts(value)
partitions = idx
out = tf.dynamic_partition(value, partitions, 10)

MAX_D = 10
def pad_zero(x):
    paddings = [[ 0, MAX_D - tf.shape(x)[0] ]]
    return tf.pad(x, paddings, "CONSTANT")

y = tf.map_fn(pad_zero, out)

with tf.compat.v1.Session() as sess:
    print(sess.run(out))
```

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/util/nest.py in assert_same_structure(nest1, nest2, check_types)
    178   try:
--> 179     _pywrap_tensorflow.AssertSameStructure(nest1, nest2, check_types)
    180   except (ValueError, TypeError) as e:

ValueError: The two structures don't have the same nested structure.

First structure: type=list str=[tf.int32, tf.int32, tf.int32, tf.int32, tf.int32, tf.int32, tf.int32, tf.int32, tf.int32, tf.int32]

Second structure: type=Tensor str=Tensor("map_6/while/Pad:0", shape=(10,), dtype=int32)

More specifically: Substructure "type=list str=[tf.int32, tf.int32, tf.int32, tf.int32, tf.int32, tf.int32, tf.int32, tf.int32, tf.int32, tf.int32]" is a sequence, while substructure "type=Tensor str=Tensor("map_6/while/Pad:0", shape=(10,), dtype=int32)" is not
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just use `pad_sequences` method in keras package. For example, I'm gonna do like below:

```
input = [[1], [2, 2], [3, 3, 3]]
padded_input = tf.keras.preprocessing.sequence.pad_sequences(input, padding='post')
```

`padded_input` will become exactly what you want:

```
>>padded_input

array([[1, 0, 0],
       [2, 2, 0],
       [3, 3, 3]])
```

Then you can just use `tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices` like normal. Since they all have the same length now, it would be fine.

Comment: I got an error. "ValueError: `sequences` must be a list of iterables. Found non-iterable: Tensor("DynamicPartition_13:0", shape=(?,), dtype=int32)"

Comment: I've to add padding to the output of `dynamic_partition`.

Comment: You can just pass a normal Python list to the `pad_sequences` method. After that you create a tensor from the padded array returned by `pad_sequences`.

Comment: I want to pad to a tensor, not a list of tensor. If I add `pad_sequence` to `out = tf.dynamic_partition(value, partitions, 10)` I'm getting above error.

Comment: I'm kind of confused. Why do you want to convert the input to tensor first and do all the preprocessing, whereas it would be much easier to do some pre-processing first and then stuff the result into tf.data.Dataset?

Comment: Actually, I kind of require things to happen like this.

Answer (score 0):

I simply iterated over the list and padded zeroes accordingly.

```
value = tf.constant([1,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4,4,5,5,5,5,5])
y, idx, count = tf.unique_with_counts(value)
partitions = idx
out = tf.dynamic_partition(value, partitions, 5)

for i in range(len(out)):
    paddings = [[ 0, MAX_D - tf.shape(out[i])[0] ]]
    out[i] = tf.pad(out[i], paddings, "CONSTANT")

out = tf.convert_to_tensor(out)

with tf.compat.v1.Session() as sess:
    print( sess.run(out) )
```